# $ E(f(X_0)f'(X_l)) = E(f'(X_0) f(X_l)) $ for a stationary process?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stationarity

I have a stationary process $\{X_t\}_{t\in\mathbb N}$ on $\mathbb R$ and two functions $f, f': \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$.

Does the equation
$$ E(f(X_0)f'(X_l)) = E(f'(X_0) f(X_l)) $$
hold?

---

Do I need strict stationarity or does weak stationarity suffice for the equation to hold?

---

I tried to show
$$ 
P(f(X_0)f'(X_l) > x) =  P(f'(X_0)f(X_l) > x) 
$$
but didn't succeed so far.

Comment: You will need strict stationarity.

Comment: If I have strict stationarity, how do I prove the equation?

Comment: It's immediate from the definition of stationarity and the commutativity of multiplication.